# Are standard text files NULL-terminated?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, pointers, null

I am writing a C++ program that reads a file and then sends it to another class as a character array. Because character arrays only get passed by pointer, all size is lost.

The file it'll be reading will be a text file. Are text files null terminated?

Preferably I do not want to use a Vector as I really don't need any of it's features but the size of the array.

Comment: No, text files are not `NULL` terminated. Either you can append (by the function/method which reads from file) in buffer or maintain another variable to hold length

Comment: @VoidPointer Length Parameter it is.

Comment: Relevant: https://latedev.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/all-about-eof/

Comment: Re: "I don't need any of its features but the size of the array": so don't use any of its features but the size of the array. My car can go 70 miles an hour on a highway, but that doesn't mean I can't use it to go to the grocery store. Oh, and you'll find that the memory management that `std::vector` does behind the scenes will save you from many headaches.

Comment: @PeteBecker I am doing this because I want to learn these things though, so maybe picking the easy way out might not be so useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.
Files have a known length, so they do not need any terminator byte.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I'm just going to send an int to specify the length of the array.

Answer (score 4):

no text files are not NULL terminated. You need to check for EOF (End Of File)
I think

```
cin.eof()
```

is what you are searching. It returns true if the end of file is reached.

Comment: But **don't** do it in a loop condition. The `eof` flag isn't set until a read operation fails due to EOF, so if you check `eof` in a loop condition then you will loop once to many.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not. But many C/C++ function to read strings from files appends zero termination to returned data.

Answer (score -1):

use eof rather than finding null character ...
for example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
ifstream iFile("myfile.txt");   // myfile.txt has integers, one per line
while (!iFile.eof())
{
int x;
iFile >> x;
cerr << x << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never use eof() in a loop condition.